# Best way to store an array currently in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two arrays that I am using within a controller that are 50-100 length long. It's getting bulky within the controller and want store it somewhere else (note that the arrays will not change and no data will be added to them). I am thinking that I would be able to store it in a database or even another file within my rails app.

What would be the best place to store them and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You can store it in another file. I will consider a yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same case. I created a global `constant` array in the corresponding `Model`.

In the `model`

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  ARRAY_FIRST = [value-1, value-2, ....., value-n]
  ARRAY_SECOND = [value-1, value-2, ....., value-n]

end
```

Access above `arrays` in the `controller`

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

   def your_action
      YourModel::ARRAY_FIRST
      YourModel::ARRAY_SECOND
   end

end
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Nitin - thanks for the help. When I try using your example, I get an `undefined method 'nameofarray'` when using the specific controller action. Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the `array` name, model name where it is declared and the way of accessing the that `array` in the controller?

Comment: name of array = `randomMessage`, model name = `Attack`, Accessing array = `Attack::randomMessage`

Comment: Ohh... It's a local variable. Change it to RANDOM_MESSAGE. Then Attack::RANDOM_MESSAGE